# widget.newSwitch() On-Off Switch doesn't work when "moved"

Tags: lua, coronasdk

On-Off Switch - widget.newSwitch() doesn't work when I "move" the switch, it works only when I press.

I've tried setting "onEvent" but looks like it's completely ignored as nothing happens.

```
local widget = require( "widget" )

-- Handle press events for the checkbox
local function onSwitchPress( event )
    local switch = event.target
    print( "Switch with ID '"..switch.id.."' is on: "..tostring(switch.isOn) )
end

-- Create the widget
local onOffSwitch = widget.newSwitch
{
    left = 250,
    top = 200,
    style = "onOff",
    id = "onOffSwitch",
    onPress = onSwitchPress
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "moving" in this context ?

Comment: dragging the switcher to on or off instead of pressing.

Comment: Please show the code you used when you tried onEvent strategy, definitely need to see that. Also, what makes you think you should be able to slide it? I've never tried and I'm not seeing any indication in the docs that this is possible.

Comment: because it's logical. just change onPress with onEvent

Answer (score 0):

The On-Off switch widget has two states: **onPress** and **onRelease**.
*OnPress* is called when we touch the switch.
 *OnRelease* is called when we release the switch.
 There is no event like *onMove*. This is why you cannot tap the move event.

See the [link](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newSwitch.html) for more details.